# How to view the docker image/container limit? And how to modify it while we run "docker build"?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-machine

The output of docker info is as follows:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 47
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 49
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-88-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 48
Total Memory: 125.8 GiB
Name: woodhouse02
ID: ON2Y:DX5E:KZT2:BEFK:4Q7E:QCKT:BZBA:JHCN:QYLM:5QEC:JJIH:3UWY
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

As docker info has no "Base Device Size" , I am unable to find out what the maximum default size of an image/container is.

Issue:
A server went offline as all the docker containers in that system ran out of space, but the containers on the machine had just used 25% of the allotted space.

The space occupied by all processes are as follows.

```
root@machine:~# df -h -l
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        63G  4.0K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       13G  2.0M   13G   1% /run
/dev/dm-1                   46G   11G   33G  25% /
none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        63G  3.0M   63G   1% /run/shm
none                       100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                  465M   62M  375M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_local  831G   73M  788G   1% /local
none                        46G   11G   33G  25% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ba5af540ce296b500fbc377edcfdf3feac171e3ffab6353498fc910119d76bd6
shm                         64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/9ca29b621bf7626590e4c0eb4aca394235267ed9bdd85750f98740de80d63471/shm
none                        46G   11G   33G  25% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/09de70d6c888b865c91984d885415d4f84ada73b9e768c73261ce43fda64fa25
none                        46G   11G   33G  25% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/251eb33f72cdab6d381a41cc127bc71fc635cdce7c97be490bc18dcb31c24adf
none                        46G   11G   33G  25% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/76955f1cf85c1070dc4a3fa02aeb4211a4c84c72133b5bcedb8e4f33fdc7d381
shm                         64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8aab30ea0cc2e73cc6f722c705209429032f237f01a5fd7f918e573ad041ba55/shm
shm                         64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5f6fe23bf1e49b6732fff93f91448d480d9dd02c0ffd5e23ebec2eb0530ee912/shm
shm                         64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/d6dee9f5ffa4966c90870d9502de67208381b0f2ce71c95fce6cd3859e470551/shm
```

How can I find out what the default docker image/container limit is. It must be the standard 10.74GB (as the failure occured at ~11GB). But I am unable to find this information.

Also, how can one modify this? I want to increase the limit to 100GB.
Is it possible to set the limit when you execute "docker run" or "docker build"

Comment: There's no image/container limit. Just normal fs limits. You might get more help with this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault. (try a `df -i` too)

Comment: @Matt Yes this command did help and it shows that I had a ton of space before my dockers died. Still unable to figure out the issues, but I haven't the issue again yet. Hope it continues to work fine

Answer (score 0):

You set limit to docker-machine on its creation (RAM,CPU,HDD).
And every container is like a process on normal OS.
So you just create new machine with your preferences.

Comment: It is said that there is no limit. But the dockers did show no memory error thought that machine had 8TB of space. (at least 7TB is unused) I'll just have to wait till I face it again to debug it right this time.